# Russell Libby's Pipes components

Tags: delphi, components, named-pipes

Does anyone know where I could download Russell Libby's named pipes
components? All the links I can find point to

http://home.roadrunner.com/~rllibby/source.html

Which is no longer alive.

HMcG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the TPipeServer and TPipeClient source code [here](http://r3code.livejournal.com/117012.html). Looks like the original Russell Libby's code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the version I have on my system. I tried posting it directly in this comment but it is too long. This source code should work on Delphi 6 and up (including Delphi 2009, 2010, and XE).
[I posted it here](http://micksmix.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/named-pipes-unit-for-delphi/).

For detailed directions on how to generally turn this source file into a design-time component, please follow [About.com’s Delphi blog instructions here](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/ss/newcomponentbpl.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There's an updated/forked version on GitHub now:
https://github.com/superflexible/NamedPipesForDelphi

Comment: please read [**How to not be a spammer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.