# Read/write example codes for TPipeServer and TPipeClient components and security check

Tags: delphi, windows-services, ipc, delphi-2010, named-pipes

I need IPC between a windows service and a GUI application both written in **Delphi 2010**. I decided to use named pipe for this.
I built and installed successfully Russell Libby's TPipeServer and TPipeClient components ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132894/russell-libbys-pipes-components)).
I followed other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512366/how-do-i-send-a-string-from-one-instance-of-my-delphi-program-to-another).
But my service received only empty messages from the client. After many test I concluded that I was using those components erroneously, so i don't want to post any code here.
So I'm looking for a valid example about how these components work in order to **write/read** strings in a named pipe (from client to server and viceversa). Any help is really appreciated, even using other free named pipes components or source codes.
Thank you.

**Edit:** I need a valid way to pass security check in windows server 2008 / windows vista / windows 7

Comment: The [Cromis-IPC](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-ipc/) component has an example for doing some basic IPC communication between a client and a server.

Comment: Communication using named pipes on the same computer should be easy with respect to security checks. Between different computers though, permissions will have to be implemented.

Comment: i need example code for these components. if server and client are on a server and i RDP connected to it, need i to implement permissions on named pipe? I think not but it's better to ask.

Comment: There is a demo in the component zip download, and also an example on the download site. I don't think you will have any problems with permissions, you might also want to read MS doc about [Named Pipe Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365600(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You did't help me with Russell Libby's components but your components do their job. Answer my question to get it accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Cromis-IPC](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-ipc/) component by Iztok Kacin is a versatile IPC communication Delphi component utilizing windows `named pipes`. On the given link is a client/server example, and in the source code of the component is a full example.

The Cromis IPC can be used for process communication within the same computer as well as communication between computers on a network. Permissions are easy to handle when doing communication within the same computer. For a detailed description how to handle permissions, see windows doc [Named Pipe Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).